# NSMutableArray can't be added to

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mutability

I've had this sort of problem before, and it didn't get a satisfactory answer.

I have a viewcontroller with a property called "counties" that is an NSMutableArray. I'm going to drill down a navigation screen to a view that is about selecting the counties for a geographical search. So the search page drills down to the "select counties" page.

I pass `NSMutableArray *counties` to the second controller as I push the second one on the navigation stack. I actually set that second controller's "selectedCounties" property (also an NSMutableArray) with a pointer to my first controller's "counties", as you'll see below.

When I go to `addObject` to that, though, I get this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Here's my code:

in SearchViewController.h:

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController 
{
    ....
    NSMutableArray *counties;
}

....
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *counties;
```

in SearchViewController.m:

```
- (void)getLocationsView
{
    [keywordField resignFirstResponder];
    SearchLocationsViewController *locationsController = 
            [[SearchLocationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchLocationsView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationsController animated:YES];
    [locationsController setSelectedCounties:self.counties];
    [locationsController release];
}
```

in SearchLocationsViewController.h:

```
@interface EventsSearchLocationsViewController : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    ...
    NSMutableArray *selectedCounties;

}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *selectedCounties;
```

in SearchLocationsViewController.m (the point here is, we're toggling each element of a table being active or not in the list of selected counties):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.selectedCounties containsObject:[self.counties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        //we're deselcting!
        [self.selectedCounties removeObject:[self.counties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_check_inactive.png"]];
    }
    else {
        [self.selectedCounties addObject:[self.counties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_check_active.png"]];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

We die at `[self.selectedCounties addObject....` there.

Now, when I NSLog myself `[self.selectedCounties class]`, it tells me it's an NSCFArray.

How does this happen? I understand about class bundles (or I THINK I do anyway), but this is explicitly a specific type, and it's losing it subclassing at some point in a way that kills the whole thing. I just completely don't understand why that would happen.

Comment: How do you create your counties object?

Comment: Where did you assign `counties`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're not allocating the array properly (e.g., `NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] init]`, or are assigning an `NSArray` to the `NSMutableArray` variable.  Can you post the code where you initialize the array?

Comment: Guilty as charged:
`self.counties = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Current Location", nil];`

Let me fix that and see if things suddenly work.

Comment: Bingo. The problem was, I realized as I was coding that I needed to be Mutable, and I didn't go back and fix it everywhere it needed fixing, I guess. I come from languages where things are already mutable, so this distinction isn't yet natural for me. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Where do you init the object you set as counties? Maybe you did a mistake like:

```
NSMutableArray *counties = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In this case no compile error will pop up but you cannot take changes on an array created like that!

Comment: Thanks--@eman beat you to it by a minute or two, but it's the right answer.